# How to edit my maze question to improve understandability?

Tags: discussion, support

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/103953/edit/80c5badc-356e-4204-a9e0-cb947225ae0e

Bubble got the images to display in the question but users kind of need the descriptions of the images so how do get a reversion to include the images and descriptions. Also I think I might draw the side images- they are focused using my Kindle Fire 8 HD but possibly look worse now than my first images. Trouble is clear plastic reflection and imperfections in the plastic due damage etc.  I thought my first set of images  was visible and understandable- slightly obscured.

Original pictures:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image] (stock image)
These I thought were good but someone complained about them and useful because you can see the link between the sides.

New Pictures:
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEzI3.jpg)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If all you want is to include the image descriptions, just put some text after each image describing what it shows. Also my username is bobble, not Bubble.

Comment: I am fine for anyone to see the version process. Can that be done? I am thankful if you can image process to black and white- the faces of cuboid are flat ball runs.

Comment: I have no idea what you last sentence means. As for your first one, anyone can see the revision history of your question. *But that should not be necessary to solve*. Please edit in text descriptions that appear next to your images. And we really, really can't help you take better pictures, or clarify your problem, because we don't know what you mean/want.

Comment: The faces are totally flat- each face is a flat maze.

Comment: It is the pinkness  of the original object that is the problem with the images.

Comment: I just  drew on paper the sides.

Comment: ***Add any information that you think is necessary to the original question***. I would like to make some things clear: I do not, and did not in the past, intend to solve your question. I edited it to fix the images *and that was all*. I have been commenting here with some *suggestions* to help, but I can't understand what you want. I can't help you clarify your question. **I am done helping here**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but... I started to help make a clearer question by transcribing your images into a grid (I used a spreadsheet application to do this for me - Google Sheets is a free example).

But after doing this, I discovered there was an easy solution.  I am not sure if the puzzle lies in the transcription or in the maze itself :)

BTW - happy to give my sheet away in a Google Sheet if you want it to prove to yourself that the maze is as I drew it (which it may not be).

Comment: Your transcription is perfect except one significant detail and one minor detail. Please send me the Google Sheet.

Comment: The significant detail is a on picture 4 which has a bar right near e2 that prevents exiting into E3

Comment: If you don't want share the file- it is awkward since SO doesn't like email addresses then post a blank maze image and I will correct it and include in my original  post with attribution.

Comment: I will add a link to the Google Sheets file when I get home from work - Though I can't guarantee other people won't edit it :)