# Can include answerer's content in my question when he has given some permission?

Tags: support

[How to edit my maze question to improve understandability?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/how-to-edit-my-maze-question-to-improve-understandability/7031#7031)
[How can this three dimensional ball maze be solved?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/103953/how-can-this-three-dimensional-ball-maze-be-solved?noredirect=1#comment294058_103953)

I just want to include the maze without his answer and correct it- can I do that? I was really hoping Graylocke would respond with the desired content.  He has basically said yes since he offered the file to derive it from.

Comment: Which is what I said. He hasn't given explicit permission. Is it permitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Terms of Service of Stack Exchange, any content contributed on or after 2018-05-02 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).

This states, among other things, that it can be reproduced with proper attribution.  So you are free to copy anything anyone has posted on Stack Exchange, as long as you attribute it to them.